# python tests keep running after result has been received

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

As the question pretty much sums it up, when running a python unittest, the result gets printed but the process seems never terminated. In the attached image you can see the green arrow next to the actual test case while the whole test suite still has the loading icon (even though only that single test has been run).

The following command is used for calling all the tests in the folder: `python -m unittest discover "./test" -p "*Test.py"`

The issue is consistent in pycharm as well as when calling the tests from the command line.

In fact, it is not an issue while running it locally, I just terminate them myself. However, since I have set up a pipeline in GitLab, running the tests whenever new commits have been pushed, I never get the "green ligth" to move forward.

Thank you guys for any help!

[screenshot of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVXVJ.png)

Below I have added the code, I am trying to retrieve the bitcoin price from the Binance exchange. I feel like I need to close some connection first.

```
class BinanceExchangeTest(unittest.TestCase):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    binance_config = BinanceConfig()
    self.client = Client(binance_config.api_key, binance_config.api_secret)
    self.binance_data = BinanceData(self.client)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def test_get_ask(self):
    price = self.binance_data.market_data.get_ask_price("BTCUSDT")
    self.assertIsNotNone(price, "No price returned.")
    self.assertGreater(price, 0, "No price returned.")
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the code & test in question so it can be recreated?

Comment: Or better yet, post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I updated the question @WilliamD.Irons

Comment: Most likely some process created in `__init__` is still running. Probably better to move that code into `setUp`, and add a `tearDown` that cleans it up again after the test (maybe shutdown the client, or whatever is needed).

Comment: Could you please provide a complete reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

The error was a thread that did not stop within a library.

A detailed explanation can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/45)